# Pandas dataframe throwing error when appending to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("stack.csv")

sector_select = "Col2"

df[sector_select] = ["100"]

df.to_csv("stack.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

`

stack.csv has no data other than a header: Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5

`ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)`

Im just trying to make a program where I can select a header and append data to the column under that header

You can only run it twice until it gives an error!

Comment: What contains ```df = pd.read_csv("stack.csv")``` ??

Comment: @Will stack.csv has no data other than a header: Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code runs for me.

But I assume that you would like to run something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("stack.csv")

sector_select = "Col2"

df.at[len(df), sector_select] = "100"

df.to_csv("stack.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention you can only run it twice. After the second time it throws an error!

Comment: If you run your code multiple times it keeps appends a large amount of data, it looks like its multiplying something somehow.

Comment: Ah ok, then you need to add the `index=False`, the code that I edit should work for you now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df = df.append({"Col2": 100}, ignore_index=True)
```